# JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:jboss/TransactionManager]

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, ejb, wildfly

This exception I have got in time of deployment for most simple EJB+JPA application (for xa-datasource) without maven pom (WildFly 16/17, template was generated by Eclipse 2019-6 - File -> New -> EJB Project):

Project's Java classes are not essential, may by Entity-POJO only (very simple too - id and message fields with getters/setters) as exception thrown on deployment stage.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_ONE")
public class TableOne {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "TABLE_ONE_ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int tableOneId;

    @Column(name = "VALUE", nullable = false)
    private String value;

    ...
```

I've tried to find similar case for app deployment but without success. It's some strange situation. Especially, TransactionManager is present on JNDI space and shown on WildFly Admin page as "java:jboss/TransactionManager"

Configs is:

1. jndi.properties

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=http-remoting://localhost:8080
java.naming.security.principal=master
java.naming.security.credentials=masterpass
```

2. persistence.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="MulticEJB" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:/MySqlTestXA</jta-data-source>
        <class>dev.packs.entity.TableOne</class>
         <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
          </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

3. standalone.xml

```xml
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:/MySqlTestXA" pool-name="MySqlTestXA">
    <xa-datasource-property name="ServerName">
        localhost
    </xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="DatabaseName">
        test
    </xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    <driver>mysql</driver>
    <xa-pool>
        <min-pool-size>2</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
    </xa-pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>test-user</user-name>
        <password>123456</password>
    </security>
</xa-datasource>

<driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql"/>
```

4. module.xml for mysql driver

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mysql">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

It was supposed that application in time of deploy creates table on datasource in accordance of simple set of fileds in Entity. But I see error with summary:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "MulticEJB.jar")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"MulticEJB.jar#MulticEJB\"" => "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: MulticEJB] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: MulticEJB] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: unable to find transaction manager
    Caused by: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:jboss/TransactionManager]
    Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jboss -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.jboss"}}
```

What is may be wrong for that simple application?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is jndi.properties. EJB's bean doesnt need for it as provided for JNDI service inside of Application Service. Otherwise Bean reads jndi.properties and try to go like as remote client. So, Bean doesn't see [java:jboss/TransactionManager] from internal JNDI namespace.

Solution is deleting jndi.properties from project.

This case was adviced on JBossDeveloper https://developer.jboss.org/thread/280472 by Frank Langelage. I mark respect to him here too.